# Centering div and its elements in Django project

Tags: html, css, django

I'm diving into Django for my first project, and I'm stuck with centering stuff on my site. What I'm trying to do is create a div that holds all the content on the site except for the navigation bar. I want this div to sit right in the middle of the screen and take up 50% of the width. And, of course, all the stuff inside that div should be centered too. I've tried a few things, but it's not quite working. Take a look at what I've got:

[image]

Here is the template:

```
<html>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    img[src="/media/images/crate_bar.png"] {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    img[src="/media/images/logo.png"] {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        top: 0;
    }

    #logo {

        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main_container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #second_container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>
<div id="logo">
    <img src="/media/images/crate_bar.png">
    <a href="{% url 'mainapp:home_view' %}"><img src="/media/images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
</div>
<h1>
    {% if user.is_superuser %}
    <a href="{% url 'mainapp:new_article' %}"><button type=" button">New article</button></a>
    {% endif %}
    {% block content %}
    <div id="main_container">
        <div id="second_container">
            <ul>
                {% for article in list_of_articles %}
                {% if article.article_image %}
                <img src="{{article.article_image.url }}" height="200" width="450">
                {% endif %}
                <p>{{article.publication_date}}</p>
                <h1><a href="{% url 'mainapp:article_view' article.id %}">{{article.title}}</a></h1>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `body` tag to your html, and then style it as below. (I see that there is no body tag in your html)

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

then for each container you want to have, you can have the following css style

```
#main_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#second_container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I do not have a body tag, but it seems it is there by default: changes in body styling affect how the page is displayed. But still, your method does not work, everything got messed up even more. Also, I think you meant "text-align", not "text-alight"

Comment: Yes I meant text-align, I have the typo in the answer. Can you update the HTML with a body tag and then try?

Comment: I have updated the answer with new properties to center align everything. Have a try with this one.